# maas 1.9.5 dhcp providing 127.0.1.1 as dhcp server, failing tftp

Tags: 14.04, maas, dhcp

When I last added machines commissioning worked as it should.  Now the console of a machine attempting to commission shows **DCHP IP: 127.0.1.1** and no TFTP address.  Only change I see since it last worked correctly is MaaS updated to 1.9.5+bzr4599-0ubuntu1~14.04.2 (based on file dates of the packages).

As you might expect, commissioning fails, as does deployment

/etc/hosts doesn't contain 127.0.1.1 for named server IP

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.0.1.1        maasCtrl
```

nor does resolv.conf base or head (both empty).  The cluster interface page shows 10.0.1.1 as the server IP.

clusterd/conf entries:

```
cluster_uuid: <cluster uid>
maas_url: http://10.0.1.1/MAAS
```

When I commission a mode I see activity in mass.log, but not clusterd.log.    regiond.log shows

```
017-10-27 23:33:23 [-] 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2017:23:33:23 +0000] "GET /MAAS/rpc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 464 "-" "provisioningserver.rpc.clusterservice.ClusterClientService"
```

when I tell the machine to provision.  I note the 127.0.0.1, but the error is 127.0.1.1.  syslog for mac address shows

```
Oct 27 23:43:47 MaaSServer dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:9e:01:bc:eb:e8 via eth0
Oct 27 23:43:48 MaaSServer dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10.0.2.109 to 08:9e:01:bc:eb:e8 via eth0
Oct 27 23:43:50 MaaSServer dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.2.109 (127.0.1.1) from 08:9e:01:bc:eb:e8 via eth0
Oct 27 23:43:50 MaaSServer dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.0.2.109 to 08:9e:01:bc:eb:e8 via eth0
```

I've looked for articles on how to interpret the DHCPREQUEST line to understand the 127.0.1.1, but haven't found anything that addresses the parenthetical part, while the rest seems obvious to me.  Using dhcping, I request an IP, and the results have **Server identifier: 127.0.1.1**, which would seem to indicate that the dhcp is identifying itself 127.0.1.1

/var/lib/maas/dhcpd.conf looks like this (header comments removed)

```
option arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16; # RFC4578
option path-prefix code 210 = text; #RFC5071

if option arch = 00:0E {
          filename "pxelinux.0";
          option path-prefix "ppc64el/";
       } elsif option arch = 00:07 {
          filename "bootx64.efi";
       } elsif option arch = 00:0B {
          filename "grubaa64.efi";
       } elsif option arch = 00:0C {
          filename "bootppc64.bin";
       } else {
          filename "pxelinux.0";
       }
class "PXE" {
        match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 3) = "PXE";
        default-lease-time 30;
        max-lease-time 30;
}
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
       interface "eth0";
       ignore-client-uids true;
       option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
       option broadcast-address 10.0.255.255;
       option domain-name-servers 10.0.1.1;
       option domain-name "maas";
       option routers 10.0.1.1;
       option ntp-servers 10.0.1.1;
       range dynamic-bootp 10.0.1.100 10.0.32.220;
}

omapi-port 7911;
key omapi_key {
    algorithm HMAC-MD5;
    secret "<deleted>";
};
omapi-key omapi_key;
```

I don't see 127.0.1.1, or the system name, or localhost

Comment: **I am giving up on this problem, moving to 1.6 & 2.2 **

Comment: Never mind, I'm not giving up.

Answer (score 0):

dhcpd.conf.template had been changed to no longer providing the "next-server" option.

dhcpd.conf did not state the next server IP.

I'm not sure why this caused dhcpd to report the IP to 127.0.1.1, instead of providing no IP.

I don't generally touch the template files, so it must have been the result of the update.  If I get a chance, I will use a VM to verify the update being the cause.

---

Addendum to answer.  Below is the `dhcpd.conf.template` that I had, that produced the `dhcpd.conf` that didn't have `next-server`.  By adding

```
   next-server {{dhcp_subnet['router_ip']}};
```

after line 25

```
   option domain-name {{dhcp_subnet['domain_name']}}";
```

everything started working again

```
# WARNING: Do not edit /var/lib/maas/dhcpd.conf yourself.  MAAS will overwrite any
# changes made there.
#
# Instead, edit /etc/maas/templates/dhcp/dhcpd.conf.template and your changes
# will be present whenever MAAS rewrites the DHCP configuration.  Update and save
# the cluster's configuration in MAAS to trigger an update to this file.

option arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16; # RFC4578
option path-prefix code 210 = text; #RFC5071

{{bootloader}}
class "PXE" {
        match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 3) = "PXE";
        default-lease-time 30;
        max-lease-time 30;
}

{{for dhcp_subnet in dhcp_subnets}}
subnet {{dhcp_subnet['subnet']}} netmask {{dhcp_subnet['subnet_mask']}} {
       interface "{{dhcp_subnet['interface']}}";
       ignore-client-uids true;
       option subnet-mask {{dhcp_subnet['subnet_mask']}};
       option broadcast-address {{dhcp_subnet['broadcast_ip']}};
       {{if dhcp_subnet.get('dns_servers')}}
       option domain-name-servers {{dhcp_subnet['dns_servers']}};
       {{endif}}
       option domain-name "{{dhcp_subnet['domain_name']}}";
       {{if dhcp_subnet['router_ip'] }}
       option routers {{dhcp_subnet['router_ip']}};
       {{endif}}
       {{if dhcp_subnet.get('ntp_server')}}
       option ntp-servers {{dhcp_subnet['ntp_server']}};
       {{endif}}
       range dynamic-bootp {{dhcp_subnet['ip_range_low']}} {{dhcp_subnet['ip_range_high']}};
}
{{endfor}}

omapi-port 7911;
key omapi_key {
    algorithm HMAC-MD5;
    secret "{{omapi_key}}";
};
omapi-key omapi_key;
```

Comment: bug sent to launchpad
https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1729913